# How can I do to use a loop for using Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I have that variable in robot framework :

`${${user}.COUNTRY}` which contains `[UK, Australia]`

If I want to access to the first element I have to do that : `${${user}.COUNTRY}[0]` and that `${${user}.COUNTRY}[1]` for the second.

I mean something like that works :

`Click Element    //span[myattribute="${${user}.COUNTRY}[0]"]`

I would like to click on all the elements contained in the list. I tried that :

```
FOR ${item} in @{${${user}.COUNTRY}}
    Click Element    //span[myattribute="${item}"]
END
```

But I got that error : `No keyword with name 'FOR ${item} in @{${${user}.COUNTRY}} ' found.`

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

@{${user}.COUNTRY}   variable declaration was incorrect

Use this format **@{Country}**  for list items

```
FOR   |   ${user}  |  IN   |  @{Country}
   Click Element    Xpath="locator"
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra $ in the variable expansion.
You should confirm with:

```
Log Many    @{${user}.COUNTRY}
```

```
FOR    ${item}    in    @{${user}.COUNTRY}
    Click Element    //span[myattribute="${item}"]
END
```

Note: I have not experimented